# Shaders not loading in web based viewers

Tags: three.js, gltf

I had a fbx which I converted into glb using fbx2gltf npm package then compressed it using

*gltf-pipeline -i model.glb -o modelDraco.glb -d*

( Final glb can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E9Y7DbZCxoWiFJlhjlx8WDm2nbNhJRHT/view?usp=sharing. )
The file appears in blender with shaders etc like following
[image]
but not in https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ or https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/ where it appears as following, without shaders n all.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your asset is exported with unlit materials. Meaning they do not respond to lighting. When inspecting the glTF asset, you can see that all materials make use of the `KHR_materials_unlit` extension.

When importing the asset in the [three.js](https://threejs.org/editor/), the car is rendered as above although no lights are present in the scene. When inspecting the materials, you see they are all of type `MeshBasicMaterial`. So `three.js` (and BabylonJS as well) properly parse and render the asset as expected.

Comment: Ok, thanks a ton, I tried changing the material and there is some improvement now but the glass is still not transparent.
https://postimg.cc/hJ9RLHx7

Comment: Sorry, but I can't provide feedback if you just share a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, here's the file I got after converting and compressing, removed --khr-materials-unlit during conversion

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Xw03HRlZzjUrIUFzjsiNDwafK9eMJAr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think alpha blend is not happening

Comment: Yes. After inspecting the material of the front glass I can say that `transparent` property is still set to `false`. So the export does not happen correctly, yet.

Comment: Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Not when using `fbx2gltf`, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230422/discussion-between-paras-and-mugen87).